# First order correction due to dipolar interaction

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, partition-function

Considering N atoms with localized moment $\vec\mu$ interacting with the magnetic field $B$ is expressed by

$$ \mathscr{H}  = - \sum^{N}_{i = 1} \mu m_i B$$ where $m_{i} \in {-l, -l + 1 ,..., l -1 , l}$

Considering that the moments interact with dipolar interaction:

$$\mathscr{H}_{dipolar} = \sum _ {i \neq j } \frac{\mu_{i} \cdot \mu_{j} - (r_{ij} \cdot \mu_{i})(r_{ij} \cdot \mu_{i}) }{r_{ij}^3}$$

I need to obtain the first order correction to the partition function at $T \rightarrow +\infty$

I know that from the definition that the partition function is:

$$Z = \sum^{l}_{m_{i} = -l} e^{-\beta \mathscr{H'}} = \sum^{l}_{m_{i} = -l} e^{-\beta \mathscr{H} + \mathscr{H}_{dipolar}}  $$ As we want the first order correction to due dipolar interaction and $\beta \rightarrow 0$ , I expanded the following term:

$$e^{-\beta \mathscr{H'}} \approx 1 - \beta \mathscr{H}_{dipolar} + O(\beta^2)$$ substituting in the partition function I get:

$$\begin{align}
Z = \sum^{l}_{m_i = -l} e^{-\beta \mathscr{H}}( 1 - \beta \mathscr{H}_{dipolar} + + O(\beta^2)) = \sum^{l}_{m_i = -l} e^{-\beta \mathscr{H}_{dipolar}} - \sum^{l}_{m_i = -l} e^{-\beta \mathscr{H}}\beta \mathscr{H}_{dipolar}
\end{align}
$$

Therefore, the first order correction is given by:

$$\delta^{(1)} Z  = \sum^{l}_{m_i = -l} e^{-\beta \mathscr{H}}\beta \mathscr{H}_{dipolar}$$

The term in $\mathscr{H}$ is easy to manipulate and get a closed form, but how do I manipulate $\mathscr{H}_{dipolar}$?

I tried expressing the dipolar Hamiltonian like:

$$\mathscr{H}_{dipolar} = \sum _ {i \neq j } \frac{\mu_{i} \cdot \mu_{j} - (r_{ij} \cdot \mu_{i})(r_{ij} \cdot \mu_{i}) }{r_{ij}^3} = \\ = \sum^N _ {i = 1 } \sum^N _ {j = 1 } \frac{\mu_{i} \cdot \mu_{j} - (r_{ij} \cdot \mu_{i})(r_{ij} \cdot \mu_{i}) }{r_{ij}^3} - \sum _ {i = j } \frac{\mu_{i} \cdot \mu_{i} - (r_{ii} \cdot \mu_{i})(r_{ii} \cdot \mu_{i}) }{r_{ii}^3} $$

However, using this trick I get and indetermination in the second term because $r_{ii} = 0$.
Any idea would be wecolme!

Edit:

Corrected the partition function.

Comment: In the second term of dipole-diploe interaction, the $r_{ij}$ should be unit vector: $\hat{r}_{ij}$.

Comment: Also, the partition function is not right. The partition function is sum over all possible energy values, i.e. sum over all configuration of $\{ m_1, m_2, m_3, ...., m_N\}$, each $m_i$ is running over $-l, -l+1, ..., +l-1, +l$. Each configuration $\{ m_1, m_2, m_3, ...., m_N\}$, is a possible energy level.

Comment: @ytlu yeah, I made a minor mistake, sorry about that. Could you help me?

Comment: The non-interaction part will become a product over single-atom partition function of atom $i$. Each single-atom partition function $Z_1$ is summing over $-l,...+l$. For each pair interation ${i, j}$ the rest of atoms are irrelavaent. Those irrelavant atom will sum over {-l, .. +l} to be $Z_o$, then you focus on the two-atom problem.

Comment: The first term of dipole interation can be written as $\mu_i \cdot \mu_j = \{ J^2 - m^2 - m^2\} /2 $, where $\vec{J}$ is $\vec{m}_1 +\vec{m}_2$.. $m^2 = l(l+1)$, and therefore $J^2 = j(j+1)$ with $j = 0, 1,2,...,2l$. But I hadn't seen the second term in quantum treatment.

Comment: Typical quantum diople-dipole interaction Hamiltonian is $H_1 = J \vec{m}_i \cdot \vec{m_j}$, where J is the coupling constant.

Comment: Here you have a problem that is not well described. You use quantum expression for magnetic interaction (with no radial wave functions, only the angular part in $|l. m>$ notation, and you have a classical dipole-dipole interaction with a radial dependent on $r^3$ and $r^5$. You cannot carry out the integral in the radial part. It requires all the information about the  physical poisiton of atoms, and very probably a numerical solution only..

Comment: So the first order correction that I got is correct but can't be solved analytically, but it can be solved numerically?

Comment: @RFeyman Unless you know all the positions of the moments, and have the radial wavefunction of the Hamitonian.

Comment: All the information that have, I wrote in the post. Should I publish my answer or delete the question?

Comment: I like to see your answer. Please show it.